# Xcode9.2 build version showing image twisted in ios8.1

Tags: image, ios8.1, xcode9.2

[image]

But use xcode9.1 it shows well.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a bug of Xcode 9.2. Just use Xcode 9.1.

Answer (score 0):

As for now, there are two ways:

1. move images from Assets.xcassets to bundle (thus loaded image from file instead of assets);
2. still use Xcode 9.1 till apple fixes the bug. (bug has been reported to apple)